# Cache.aspx showing wrong Max sizes

Tags: caching, admin-pages

On one of our projects (Sitecore 8.2 initial) we see something weird in the `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx` page:

[image]

As you can see the MaxSize value is a bit high. (Count, Size and Delta are not 0 everywhere btw, they seem normal). On other 8.2 projects we don't seem to have this issue. One difference that I can think of is that this project has a lot of sites (and their cache was not yet tuned).

Has anyone seen this before? Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is related to the '**Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits**' setting in the web.config file. When set to true, Sitecore ignores any maximum cache sizes specified in the web.config file.

Please change the value to "false" like bellow :

```
<setting name="Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits" value="false"/>
```

Comment: this is not recommended due to performance issues.

Comment: If you enable cache size limits. you need to make sure that you allocated enough memory to each cache for good performance. If you have enough memory and a 64bit OS tho, just leave them disabled.